# AssemblyInitialize is called twice when CodedUi and UnitTests are in the same assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, vs-unit-testing-framework

In my assembly I have tests of 2 types: [CodedUI] and [TestClass]. The AssemblyInitialize method is called twice: for tests of each type.

Is there a way to make the AssemblyInitialize method run only once?

Comment: Just use a static bool variable.

Comment: Thanks, Hasan. I tried something similar (an integer), but was set to 0 after tests of 1 type finished and before the tests of the 2nd type were about to start.

But could be I am missing something in the code. I will have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should be setting the [AssemblyInitialize()] attribute on only one initialization method in each class of test classes.  This method is called before ClassInitialize and TestInitialize.  Therefore, it should only be called once per test run.  More info can be found here =>  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx